# AutoHotKey script switching between virtual desktop using ^!LButton and ^!RButton highlights one app from the start menu

Tags: windows, autohotkey, virtual-desktop

I've created an AutoHotKey script which allows me to switch between virtual desktops more comfortably but there is a weird issue that makes a random (but most often the most recent) app ask for attention.

```
^!LButton:: Send #^{Left}

^!RButton:: Send #^{Right}
```

An app highlighting itself:

[image]

Changing `^` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) to `+` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>) doesn't remove the issue.
Changing the whole input sequence to <kbd>F4</kbd> (for one case) and <kbd>F8</kbd> for another removed the issue, but it's not ergonomic and they aren't the keys I'd like to use.

Comment: There's a similar stackoverlow question but it's not helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556884/why-does-switching-desktops-with-autohotkey-make-my-taskbar-icons-highlight-oran The suggestion in comments doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Works fine here. Is that all the code in your script? Are there other parallel running scripts?

Comment: @user3419297 That's the whole code. There are no other scripts. I have 5 virtual desktops and some apps on each one. (it is a bit of an issue because I have some communicators open and it's confusing when they get highlighed without a reason).

Comment: All right. As an addendum, the solution I proposed didn't work, so it's been removed. Once again, my apologies. That is really strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^!LButton:: 
    Send #^{Left}
    Click up
    FocusForemostWindow()
return


^!RButton:: 
    Send #^{Right}
    FocusForemostWindow()
return


#If GetKeyState("Ctrl") and GetKeyState("Alt")

    LButton::
    RButton::
    return

#If

; Give focus to the foremost window on the current desktop.
FocusForemostWindow() {
    list := ""
    WinTitle := ""
    ; ToolTip
    ; get a list of all windows on the current desktop
    WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        WinGetTitle, WinTitle, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (WinTitle="")
            continue
        WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If !(exStyle & 0x100)
            continue
        If !IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(this_ID)
            continue
        IfWinNotActive, ahk_id %this_ID%
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_id %this_ID%
            WinWaitActive, ahk_id %this_ID% 
        }
        ; ToolTip, %WinTitle%   
            break
    }
    Sleep, 30
}

; https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=64295#p64295
; Indicates whether the provided window is on the currently active virtual desktop:

IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(hWnd) {
    onCurrentDesktop := ""
    CLSID := "{aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a}" 
    IID := "{a5cd92ff-29be-454c-8d04-d82879fb3f1b}" 
    IVirtualDesktopManager := ComObjCreate(CLSID, IID)  
    Error := DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(IVirtualDesktopManager+0), 3*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", IVirtualDesktopManager, "Ptr", hWnd, "IntP", onCurrentDesktop)
    ObjRelease(IVirtualDesktopManager)  
    if !(Error=0)
        return false, ErrorLevel := true
    return onCurrentDesktop, ErrorLevel := false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing this script but I'm still getting highlighted apps. I kind of decided to live with it so it's not an issue for me anymore.